# Azure Pipelines Wildcard advice

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to copy all the .nupkg files recursively, but only from directories which their name start with "Zafiro.".

I've created this task in the azure-pipelines.yml

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
        Contents: '**\Zafiro.*\*.nupkg'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        flattenFolders: true
```

But it copies 0 files.
It seems the wildcard ('**\Zafiro.**.nupkg') isn't working as expected.

How do I get what I want?

Comment: The agent are Windows or Linux?

Comment: It's a Windows agent

Comment: There are some nested folders or just one level `Zafiro.*` with `*.nupkg` files?

Comment: If you're only building 1 package in the pipeline, use `**\*.nupkg` that will filnd the file for you. Otherwise, just try `Zafiro.*\*.nupkg`

Comment: If that still doesn't work, maybe the full definition will `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\**\Zafiro.*\*.nupkg` (that's how I get msix packages), but I'm not fully confident in the way the CopyFiles Task does it, I have had trouble with it before.

Comment: There are many packages being built, under different folders with a shared root

Comment: @SuperJMN Why you have `.` in the `Zafiro.*`? the names of the folders are with `.`? I success to copy with `**/Zafiro*/*.nupkg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Pipelines Wildcard advice

The pattern `Zafiro.*` should be work. I test it with a sample in my side, and it works fine.

As test, I upload some nuget packages in different folder include the test folder `Zafiro.Test` in the repo directly instead of create the nuget packages:

[image]

Now, I use the same YAML file to test it and in order to see the result more intuitively, I replace the `TargetFolder` to my local folder:

```
pool:
  name: MyPrivateAgent

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\Zafiro*\*.nupkg'
    TargetFolder: 'D:\PublishFolder'
    flattenFolders: true
```

Then the result:

[image]

So, the pattern Zafiro.* should be work.

To resolve this issue, first, we need to make sure we have the nuget package in the `Zafiro.*` in the `Agent.BuildDirectory` folder. We could change the Contents `'**\Zafiro*\*.nupkg'` to `'**\*.nupkg'` to check if we have nuget package in the `Agent.BuildDirectory` folder first.

Second, just like Shayki Abramczyk said, we could try to remove `.` in the `Zafiro.*`.

If above still not resolve your question, please share the debug log for this copy task.